# How to call a c# Rest Service from JQuery

Tags: jquery, rest, .net-4.0

I have a REST service written in .NET4 C# code and the following url is displayed in the help page to call the service.

```
http://myservice/ALWebService/{ASS}
```

I can not for the life of me get my jQuery ajax to call into the service although I get no exception it always returns error in the call back.

The code I use to call the thing is:

```
function DoPost() {
        $.ajax({
                        cache: false,
                        url: ' http://myservice/',
                        dataType: "JSON",
                        type: 'POST',
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        data: 'ass{%22Id%22:10,%22Urn%22:%22AS1234%22,%22Description%22:%22Test%20Description%22,%22AssetStatusId%22:3,%22ExpiryDate%22:%220001-01-01T00:00:00%22,%22OwnerId%22:0,%22TeamId%22:0,%22ProductCode%22:null,%22Keywords%22:null}',      

                        success: function (transactionid, response, arguments) {
                            alert("entry successfully added");
                        },
                        error: function (transactionid, response, arguments) {
                            alert("add entry failed: " + response.responseText);
                        }

                    });

    }
```

The .NET code:

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "{ass}")]
    public int AddToLibrary(string ass)
    {


        return 1;
    }
```

Can anyone see what I may be doing wrong as I just can not seem to get this right.

Thanks

Comment: *"`error: function (transactionid, response, arguments)`"* That's not the signature of the `error` function in jQuery's [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax). Not saying that's the problem, but it's *a* problem. :-) Similarly, the `success` function doesn't get called with the arguments you declare for it either.

Comment: Have you tried calling the webservice from a web browser or have you written some c# test client?

Comment: Tried from web browser with little success. Unfortunately I need to give a sample to the classic asp developers so need to get it sorted in jQuery hence no c# test client.

Answer (score 2):

The URL does not match the suggested, try this:

```
url: 'http://myservice/ALWebService/',
```

Comment: I get a 404 when I add anything after the myservice/

Comment: @Morn: Then that's your problem, your web service isn't set up correctly, nothing to do with jQuery, the problem is at the server side.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Hmm so I try this (AssetLibraryWebService/AddToLibrary{ASS}) I get a 'Method not allowed' message, when I AssetLibraryWebService/AddToLibrary) I get a 'Endpoint not found' message. What I dont get is why I can access the help page for the service by not call it using the methods it suggests.